# Exibição de UL falha na altura

Tags: css, css3

Tenho uma **UL** e suas **li's** tem **50px** de **altura**.
No caso a altura da **UL** deve obedecer esses **50px**

Acontece que em algumas **li's** eu tenho **imagens** nelas e isso está causando uma **aumento** na **altura** da **li**.

O problema: Só ocorre no **Chrome**.

Existe algum **hack** para corrigir isso?

Veja no **Firefox**. (Não ocorre a falha)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Agora no **Chrome**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ainda estou aprendendo **CSS**.

```css
/* CSS Document */
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
*, 
*:before, 
*:after, 
*:active, 
*:hover {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
    border:0;
    outline: none; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: content-box; /*Comprimir(diminuir) as medidas do elemento para não aumentá-lo quando adicinar margin e padding*/
}
ul {
 list-style: none;

}
ul li { 
 height: 50px; 
}
ul.topo{
 background-color: #CCCCCC;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
ul.topo li {
 text-align: center;
}
ul.ulHorizontal { 
}
ul.ulHorizontal li {
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 50px;
}
ul.ulHorizontal li img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
a, a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
button, 
input[type=button], 
input[type=submit], 
input[type=reset] {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #CCCCCC; 
}
button:hover, 
input[type=button]:hover, 
input[type=submit]:hover, 
input[type=reset]:hover {
 background-color: #DCDCDC; 
 border: 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2) solid;
}
button:active, 
input[type=button]:active, 
input[type=submit]:active, 
input[type=reset]:active {
 background-color: #FFFFFF; 
}
/************   CORES   **************/
.bgcCinza100 {
 background-color: #CCC;
}
.bgcCinza25 {
 background-color: #DCDCDC;
}
.bgcPreto100 {
 background-color: #000;
}
.bgcBranco100 {
 background-color: #FFF;
}
.bgcVermelho100 {
 background-color: #F00; 
}
.bgAzulCiano {
 background-color: #007EAE;
}
/************   CORES   **************/
.btnCarrinho {
 width: 50px;
 height: 25px;
 line-height: 15px;
 text-align: center;
}

ul#menuCategorias li {
 height: 50px; 
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ulHorizontal topo">
   <li style="width:200px">CATEGORIA</li><!--
--><li style="width:200px">NOME</li><!--
--><li style="width:100px">PREÇO</li><!--
--><li style="width:100px">FRETE</li><!--
--><li style="width:100px">TRANSPORTE</li><!--
--><li style="width:100px">EDITAR</li><!--
--><li style="width:100px">BLOQUEIO</li><!--
--><li style="width:100px">EXCLUIR</li>
</ul>
<ul class=ulHorizontal id=listaRegistros style="background-color:#F8F8F8">
  <li style="text-align:left; width:200px;">Leve</li><!--
--><li style="text-align:left; width:200px;">Produto 1</li><!--
--><li style="text-align:right; width:100px;">120.33</li><!--
--><li style="text-align:center; width:100px;"><img src ="imgs/iconeDedoJoia.png" style="height:45px;" title="Com Frete Grátis" /></li><!--
--><li style="text-align:center; width:100px;"><img src ="imgs/iconeCorreiosCaminhao.png" style="height:45px;" title="Correios" /></li><!--
--><li style="text-align:center; width:100px;"><a href="?produtos&editar&idProdutos=1"><img src="imgs/editar.png" height="30px"  title="Editar Produto"/></a></li><!--
--><li style="text-align:center; width:100px;"><a href="?produtos&bloquear&idProdutos=1" onclick="return verifica('Deseja Bloquear este produto');" ><img src="imgs/bloquear.png" height="30px"  title="Bloquear Produto" /></a></li><!--
--><li style="text-align:center; width:100px;"><a href="?produtos&excluir&idProdutos=1" onclick="return verifica('Deseja Excluir este produto?');" ><img src="imgs/excluir.png" height="30px"  title="Excluir Produto"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

Eu sei que se eu adicionar o **height** das **li's** que é de **50px** à **UL**.

```
<ul style='height=50px'>...</ul>
```

isso resolverá o problema.

Mas, seria correto fazer isso uma vez que não é **padrão** para todos os **browsers**?

Comment: Carlos coloca o HTML e o CSS completo para podermos simular seu problema, só com a imagem não da para te ajudar muito

Comment: Adicionado o código ao final da pergunta @hugocsl!

Answer (score 0):

O mais apropriado para este caso seria usar as tables do html, pois para fazer tabelas como essas elas servem bem melhor.

Tente alterar seu código para

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th>Categoria</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Preço</th>
        <th>Frete</th>
        <th>Transporte</th>
        <th>Editar</th>
        <th>Bloqueio</th>
        <th>Excluir</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Leve</td>
        <td>Produto 1</td>
        <td>120.33</td>
        <td><img src="imgs/iconeDedoJoia.png"></td>
        <td><img src="imgs/iconeCorreiosCaminhao.png"></td>
        <td><img src="imgs/editar.png"></td>
        <td><img src="imgs/bloquear.png"></td>
        <td><img src="imgs/excluir.png"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Vale lembrar que para uma melhor organização no código sempre é bom deixar todo o css em um arquivo externo.